# Find proportion of a variable across levels of another variable in sql

Tags: sql, group-by

I have the below data:

```
group_class y_prop
grp_1       1
grp_1       0
grp_2       1
grp_1       0
grp_1       0
grp_1       1
grp_3       0
grp_3       0
grp_3       0
grp_1       0
grp_1       0
grp_1       1
grp_1       0
grp_1       0
grp_3       1
grp_2       0
grp_1       0
grp_2       0
grp_1       0
grp_1       0
grp_2       0
grp_1       0
grp_1       1
grp_1       0
grp_1       0
grp_2       1
grp_2       0
grp_2       0
```

I want to find the proportion of y_prop within each group_Class as below:

```
group_class y_prop
grp_3       0.25
grp_2       0.29
grp_1       0.29
```

Can someone please help me with the sql for this?

Comment: Simply use `AVG()`? Perhaps you need to do `AVG(y_prop * 1.0)` to avoid integer arithemtics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/28c4c/7/0

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (group_class varchar2(5), y_prop int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 1)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_2', 1)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 1)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_3', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_3', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_3', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 1)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_3', 1)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_2', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_2', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_2', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 1)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_1', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_2', 1)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_2', 0)
    INTO Table1 (group_class, y_prop)
         VALUES ('grp_2', 0)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

Query -

```
select group_class, round(y_prop,2) as y_prop from (
select group_class, avg(y_prop) as y_prop
from Table1
group by group_class
order by group_class desc);
```

Output -

```
GROUP_CLASS Y_PROP
grp_3       0.25
grp_2       0.29
grp_1       0.24
```